# Found a circular dependency while saving exception - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Since 1 week I used Parse SDK. 
I have two java objects:

```
Parent parent; // extend ParseObject
Child  child;  // extend ParseObject
// child.put("parent_key",parent); -- >error
```

I want to link a child with a parent.
Following parse doc I have to do:

> https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-relational-data
>   [doc](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-relational-data)

Then doc say to call .saveinBackground() to child object and not in parent.
I tried this solution and Parse generate this expection, wihtout upload data.
I tried to call saveInBackground method to parent, but parse upload an empty object with empty fields.

Comment: how do you create the relation between child and parent?

Comment: a field of parent object contains array of Child. In the future I don't want to iterate on all childs to check a condition. I want know who is father of a single child. I want a double association 1-n. I parent has got 1-* childs, and a child has got only one parent. Because query cost so much on parse

Comment: checkout https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations and the part about authors and books. it describes your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people have my problem...
Circular dependecy because I pur an array of Child pointer intorno Parent field. And each Child has a pointer to Parent object. This mean circular. To solve this, Parent object has noto anymore array of Child. Now I use include("parentkey") query for fine alla Child and alla works great.